# Form ajax post data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i trying make form using ajax. But i get some problems to sending form vars to php file. I get error: Undefined index: name.
I check chrome dev tools and i see variable is sending. But when made echo json_encode i see in php file i get empty array. So i dont have any idea where i made misstake.

file Main.js

```js
var name = $('#user_name').val();
var lname = $('#user_lastname').val();

function formLogin(name, lname)
{
$.ajax({ url: 'database/register.php',
     data: {
         'name' : name,
         'lname' : lname
     },
     type: 'post',
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
              }
});
}
```

Html form:

```html
<form class="circleForm" id="registerForm">
     Imię: <input type="text" id="user_name"><br>
     Nazwisko: <input type="text" id="user_lastname">
    <br>
<input class="btnCircle" type="button" id="submit" value="Przejdź dalej" onclick="formLogin(name, lname)">                    
 </form>
```

Php Code:

> $dane = $_POST;
>   echo json_encode($dane);

Chrome dev:
[image]

I just want figure how can i echo this variables(name,lname) in php file register.php

Version with serialize:

```js
function formLogin() {
        var dane = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'database/register.php',
        data: {'dane': dane},
        method: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  
}
```

Then result console:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>D:\xampp\htdocs\szkola\database\register.php:8:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'dane' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
</pre>
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/szkola/database/register.php".
```

But when i go to http://localhost/szkola/database/register.php

i get this:

D:\xampp\htdocs\szkola\database\register.php:8:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Can you provide exact code which you are using to retrieve data on server side?

Comment: @VIshal i just learning ajax and make some forms etc. And now i trying make form using ajax and sending 2 inputs (name,lname) to php file and just echo it

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the way you define your variables in your Javascript and declare them inside your function, not outside :

```
function formLogin(){

    var name = $('#user_name').val();
    var lname = $('#user_lastname').val();

    $.ajax({ url: 'database/register.php',
         data: {
             'name' : name,
             'lname' : lname
         },
         type: 'post',
         dataType:'json',
         success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
         }
    });
}
```

And you need to update your HTML the same way (`formLogin()` instead of `formLogin(...,...)`) :

```
<form class="circleForm" id="registerForm">
     Imię: <input type="text" id="user_name"><br>
     Nazwisko: <input type="text" id="user_lastname">
    <br>
<input class="btnCircle" type="button" id="submit" value="Przejdź dalej" onclick="formLogin()">                    
 </form>
```

Comment: ok i will trying

Comment: i do like u write butt still i get empty array in register.php. I even tring do echo $_POST['name']; and i get thats same error about undefine index.

Comment: Try to see what's inside of your `$_POST` by doing `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: ye i do and its empty array

Comment: Then you have a problem sending the data to your PHP file. Check your Javascript data before sending it.

Comment: i edit the post i add screen from chrome dev.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful When i click submit button its not showing alert with data.

Comment: Everything is working fine with the code you showed us. Try testing everything via a `GET` form to test your PHP page on its own, with URL parameters.

Comment: This is strange because in ajax request it's clearly says Request Method as POST

Comment: @Vishal ye and i see Form Data this 2 variables is sending and i dont know why i get empty array in php file

Answer (score 0):

Try using `method` instead of `type`.

The HTML:

```
<form class="circleForm" id="registerForm">
    Imię:       <input type="text" id="user_name" name="name"><br />
    Nazwisko:   <input type="text" id="user_lastname" name="lname"><br />
    <input class="btnCircle" type="button" id="submit" value="Przejdź dalej" onclick="formLogin();">                    
</form>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function formLogin() {

    // Serialize the form
    var data = $('form').serialize();

    // Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'database/register.php',
        data: data,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Also remember that you're requesting a JSON so you have to echo a `json_encode($array)` in your PHP file for a simple string will not be returned.

Comment: I do like u write and i still get empty array. ` $dane = $_POST;
echo json_encode($dane); ` and in console i get this object with name and lname

Comment: That is what you're supposed to get. The JSON response you get is an object. You can access its information with, let's say, `console.log(data.name)` & it'll return the value of `name`.

Comment: ye i know that but i dont know how send this 2 vars to register.php i really trying it on different way but still i dont know why i get empty array or error about undefine index. I am was reading a lot of post and watching tutorials about ajax and i think my code looks good event on img i see post working but really now i dont know where i made misstake.

Comment: Try running a `console.log` for those two variables before making the Ajax request. If they are displayed in the console, that step was done right. If they are not displayed in the console, maybe there's something wrong with the way you're getting the input values.

Comment: Also, you said that you're getting an object in the console after making the Ajax request. Are the object items empty? Because the problem is somewhere in between sending the wrong values in the Ajax request and encoding them to JSON in the PHP file.

Comment: ok i made console.log without ajax and its working. When i make ajax form i get normal object:  {name: "sadasd", lname: "asdsa"}. Ye its showing object in consol when success in ajax.

Comment: That is right then, you're supposed to get that exact response from the PHP file. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: My problem is i trying get this object in php file. Next i want just make simply echo but when i do json_encode i get empty array and i dont know why even i trying print_r $_POST i get thats same empty array. When i go to http://localhost/szkola/database/register.php i just get []

Comment: Well you're creating this object from the `$_POST` array you're encoding to JSON in the PHP file. You can mess with this array and generate your own JSON for the response. And the reason why you're not being able to display anything other than JSON is because you've set the `dataType` to `json` in the Ajax call. The `dataType` is what you're expecting as a response from the PHP file. If you remove that, you'll be able to get any type of content (strings, intergers and etc).

Comment: You can access each `$_POST` item inside the PHP file as `$_POST['name']` or so.

Comment: Ok so if i get type json i get object so when i use $dane = $_POST;
echo json_encode($dane); Can i do like that?

Comment: If you remove the `dataType` setting you'll be able to run a `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP file and it'll be displayed in the console.

Comment: No i cant use $_POST['name'] becouse i get error about undefine index and when i print_r $_POST i just get Array() i delete datatypa json from ajax.

Comment: If you set the `dataType` to `json` you'll only be able to echo json-encoded arrays, which will be turnet to JavaScript objects. `json_encode()` turns a PHP `array()` into a JavaScript object (`{}`).

Comment: When i var_dump($_POST); i get D:\xampp\htdocs\szkola\database\register.php:8:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Well then there's something wrong with your Ajax call. Try this: Add some `name` attributes to the inputs (name and lname, for example) and instead of declaring variables to these inputs in your JS, declare a single variable with `$('form').serialize();`. In your Ajax call, set the `data` value to this variable you just declared. That way it should work.

Comment: I updated the answer if that helps.

Comment: i do like u write and still when i go to http://localhost/szkola/database/register.php  i see empty array i use json_encode

Comment: If you manually go to that PHP file you'll get an empty array. To test that, you have to submit the form with the inputs filled out, otherwise there is no information for the PHP to get.

Comment: Are u sure?? But when i just want make new record to database so i will be  use $_POST['data'] but its will be error about undefine index.

Comment: Yes I am sure. & there is no `$_POST['data']`. The `data` variable you declare in your JS is the serialized form, not an actual `$_POST` item. This variable will bring every input along with their values. In your PHP file, you'll be able to access each input's value by its name, like this: `$_POST['name']`. The same for other inputs, e.g.: If you want to access a serialized form's input "`<input name="user_email">`", you should go `$_POST['user_email']`. ––– `$_POST['data']` doesn't exist because `data` is just a variable containing every input.

Comment: OK really thx for explain it:D I was sure i could easy print this variable to check it to be sure its working.

Comment: No problem mate! :)